# Custom cron task in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, cron

I have module for drupal 7, called Parser. But this module doesnt have options to use cron. And since i'm bad at drupal module coding, i wanted to ask if there is any options to manually add my task from Parser to cron?

Comment: Is Parser on Drupal.org?  If so, can you provide a link to the module's project page.

Comment: No, its on some russian site, but here is guthub page
https://github.com/xandeadx/parser/zipball/master
Also there is some reworked module with cron option, but he doesnt make tables in db, that are required for work

Comment: As per your module code, it looks like its designed to use batch API, which depends on user's browser (browser queries the server to keep the process going). So you will need some refactoring in the code to make it cable to run during cron. hook_cron() is the way.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read up on what Drupal hooks do.

```
function hook_cron() {
  // Do something when cron runs.
}
```

so if you wanted to edit the parser module you would use

```
function parser_cron() {
  // Add your code that should be run on every cron run.
}
```

You might also want to look at rules as you may be able to achieve the desired results that way. It's hard to know without getting more information on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the hook "cron", in your case :

```
function parser_cron() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above post is correct you will need to hook to the cron in the module

This may help further http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7